# Hibernate cascade saving error (Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate, after following some tutorials, i tried to make my self example of storing persisting data with hibernate. 
Using: MySQL 5.7 and Hibernate 5.0.3 with Eclipse IDE.

I looked for similar topics but no solution running.

My Java Classes are:

> Dossier.java (Folder containing multiple files)

```
package com.testhibernate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Dossier {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Fichier> files;

    public Dossier()
    {
        setName("Folder");
        files = new ArrayList<Fichier>();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Fichier> getFiles()
    {
        return files;
    }

    public void addFile(Fichier a_file)
    {
        a_file.setFolder(this);
        files.add(a_file);
    }
}
```

> Fichier.java (File contained in a Folder)
>      package com.testhibernate;

```
public class Fichier {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Dossier folder;

    public Fichier()
    {
        setName("Fichier");
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setFolder(Dossier a_folder) {
        folder = a_folder;
    }

    public Dossier getFolder() {
        return (folder);
    }
}
```

I also created a class to handle save requests

> ManageDB.java (Contains starting main function)

```
package com.testhibernate.dbaccess;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import com.testhibernate.Dossier;
import com.testhibernate.Fichier;


public class ManageDB {

    private static SessionFactory factory;
    private static boolean configured = false;

    private static void log(String a_str)
    {
        System.out.println("[[MANAGEDB@: " + a_str + "]");
    }

    /**
     * @name setup
     * @brief configure the factory session
     */
    public static void setup()
    {
        log("Setup");
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
        if (!configured)
        {
            try{
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.configure();
                configuration.addClass(Dossier.class);
                configuration.addClass(Fichier.class);

                serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                        configuration.getProperties()).build();
                factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
                 configured = true;
             }catch (Throwable ex) { 
                System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
             }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @name addFolder.
     * @param a_folder the folder to save
     * @return ID of the added call.
     */
    public static Long addFolder(Dossier a_folder)
    {
        log("addFolder");
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Long folderID = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            folderID = (Long) session.save(a_folder);
            tx.commit();
        }catch(HibernateException e)
        {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            log("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally
        {
            session.close();
        }

        return(folderID);
    }

    public static Long addFile(Long folderID, Fichier a_file)
    {
        log("addFile");
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        //Load Dossier persistent object
        Dossier l_folder = (Dossier) session.load(Dossier.class, folderID);
        log("Folder@Name: " + l_folder.getName());
        log("Folder@FilesCount: " + l_folder.getFiles().size());
        //add the file
        l_folder.addFile(a_file);
        log("Folder@FilesCount: " + l_folder.getFiles().size());
        session.flush();
        return(a_file.getId());
    }

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        //Instantiate Dossier (a folder)
        Dossier folder = new Dossier();
        //Instantiate 4 Fichier objects (4 files)
        Fichier file1, file2, file3, file4;
        file1 = new Fichier();
        file2 = new Fichier();
        file3 = new Fichier();
        file4 = new Fichier();
        file1.setName("File1");
        file2.setName("File2");
        file3.setName("File3");
        file4.setName("File4");

        //Add files to the folder
        folder.addFile(file1);
        folder.addFile(file2);
        folder.addFile(file3);

        //Configure session factory
        ManageDB.setup();
        //Add folder to database
        ManageDB.addFolder(folder);
    }
}
```

Hibernate files (I used hibernate with XML, no annotations).

> hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="HibernateTestSessionFactory">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="format_sql">true</property>
  <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

> Dossier.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 20 nov. 2015 03:16:28 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.testhibernate.Dossier" table="DOSSIER">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <list name="files" table="FICHIER" access="field" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <list-index></list-index>
            <one-to-many class="com.testhibernate.Fichier" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> Fichier.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 20 nov. 2015 03:16:28 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.testhibernate.Fichier" table="FICHIER">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="folder" class="com.testhibernate.Dossier" fetch="join">
            <column name="FOLDER" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I execute the program an error occurs:

> ERROR 
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`test`.`fichier`, CONSTRAINT `FKa0k27gcqnhentsb26vm3cwki0`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `dossier` (`ID`))

When there is only one element in the ''files'' list, everything works fine.

> Database model generated automatically
>
> DOSSIER Table

```
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------
| Table   | Create Table
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------
| dossier | CREATE TABLE `dossier` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> FICHIER Table

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table

                                                                                         |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| fichier | CREATE TABLE `fichier` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FOLDER` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `files_ORDER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FKgc8774xohnq2sadsw2bum3kn7` (`FOLDER`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKa0k27gcqnhentsb26vm3cwki0` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `dossier` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKgc8774xohnq2sadsw2bum3kn7` FOREIGN KEY (`FOLDER`) REFERENCES `dossier` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

Thanks!

Comment: please be aware that you posted Dossier twice (instead of Dossier and Fichier); also the full stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: This seems to be a foreign key data modelling issue: Can you post your data model regarding the tables involved.

Comment: @Gudo thank you, i edited the question with the correct Fichier.java code.

Comment: @Norbert van Nobelen like i said im new to hibernate, where can i find the data model?

Comment: The data model is in the database: Login into mysql command line, type `use your_database_name`, type `show tables`, then type `show create table some_table_name`

Comment: @Norbert van Nobelen I updated the post with the informations you need, i'm not expert in databases so any information will be appreciated. Thx.

Comment: I do not see the real cause yet. I think I see 1 issue though in your `Dossier` **one-to-many** mapping: I would expect that to map to `fichier`.`FOLDER`. Also look at the constraints as generated by the show create table on `fichier`: You see that 2 constraints both point to `dossier(id)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out my problem.

Error was in Hibernate mapping, here's the correct version of Dossier and Folder mapping.

> Dossier mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 20 nov. 2015 03:16:28 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.testhibernate.Dossier" table="DOSSIER">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="FOLDER_ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <list name="files" table="FICHIER" access="field">
            <key>
                <column name="FOLDER_ID" />
            </key>
            <list-index></list-index>
            <one-to-many class="com.testhibernate.Fichier" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> Fichier mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 20 nov. 2015 03:16:28 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.testhibernate.Fichier" table="FICHIER">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="FILE_ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="folder" class="com.testhibernate.Dossier" fetch="join">
            <column name="FOLDER_ID" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> One to many ( Dossier -> Fichier )
>
> The one to many relation specifies a key (FOLDER_ID).

---

> Many to One ( Fichier -> Dossier )
>
> The many to one relation need to know the ID of the other (FOLDER_ID).

---

The error in the first version of mapping was to name differently the columns ID *( ID in the one-to-many and FOLDER in the many-to-one)*.

Reading Hibernate documentation helped me:

[Hibernate Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-mappings.html) goto **section 23.3. Customer/Order/Product** to see a simple example of how implement a one-to-many relation.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your Files before your Folder. But the File table has a foreign key pointing toward the Folder : it doesn't exist yet.

Just save your Folder before saving the Files.

This is not a Hibernate problem, this is a Database problem.

Comment: Hi, i think it's not a problem of creating database, cause when i put only one file to the folder.files list it works, the problem occurs when i try to put more than one files, it fails at adding the second file. I tried your suggestion, save folder first and then save files, same error occurs, :/.

Comment: It only works because you already have a folder row in your DB and it somehow matches. When you save the folder (first thing to do), it returns an ID. That ID has to be set in the files (I don't see you doing that). Then you can save the files.

Comment: I already set the folder object of the file inside the Dossier.addFile() function (see in Dossier.java code).